# How to upload image using fileuploadfield extjs + php

Tags: php, javascript, json, extjs, file-upload

I am new at using extjs. And I've been having a hard time uploading image to server. I have seen a lot of examples which I made as a guide. But I can seem to get a successful result.

Here's my code for my view:

```
items: [{
xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
id: 'form-file',
emptyText: 'Select image',
name: 'image-upload',
buttonText: 'Browse',
buttonConfig: {
iconCls: 'upload-icon'
}
},
{
xtype: 'button',
//action: 'submit',
text: 'Upload',
handler: function(){
var form = this.up('form').getForm();
form.submit({
url: 'uploadproc.php',
waitMsg: 'Loading data...',
success: function(fp, o) {
msg('Success', 'Processed file "' + o.result.file + '" on the server');
}
});

}
}

],
```

and here's my uploadproc.php file

```
<?php

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["image-upload"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["image-upload"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image-upload"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image-upload"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["image-upload"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";


if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"]))
{
echo $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image-upload"]["tmp_name"],
"upload/" . $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"];
}
}
}
else
{
echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

I keep getting this error:

Uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: Invalid file

I saved my uploadproc.php file inside my folder but outside the js folder. I'm really new to this and If someone could help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Your server should be returning structured JSON (string) instead of normal string. JSON is a representation of javascript object which usually gets created from JSON on the client-end. Javascript is then using that object to easily interact with data.

I changed uploadproc.php file to build JSON and return it. Did some changes to javascript too, so different error/success messages gets displayed.
I increased minimal upload file size ($_FILES["image-upload"]["size"]), in bytes it is pretty small. That probabbly solves the 'Invalid file' error.

This works for me:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array(
    "gif",
    "jpeg",
    "jpg",
    "png"
);
$temp        = explode(".", $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"]);
$extension   = end($temp);

$infoString = "";

if ((($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] == "image/png")) && ($_FILES["image-upload"]["size"] < 9999999)
//&& ($_FILES["image-upload"]["size"] < 20000) 
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["image-upload"]["error"] > 0) {
        die("{'success': false, 'error': '" . $_FILES["image-upload"]["error"] . "'}");
    } else {
        $infoString .= " Upload: " . $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"] . "<br>";
        $infoString .= " Type: " . $_FILES["image-upload"]["type"] . "<br>";
        $infoString .= " Size: " . ($_FILES["image-upload"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        $infoString .= " Temp file: " . $_FILES["image-upload"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"])) {
            die("{'success': false, 'error': '" . $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"] . " already exists.'}");
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image-upload"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"]);
            $infoString .= " Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["image-upload"]["name"];
        }
    }
} else {
    die("{'success': false, 'error': 'File too big or invalid!'}");
}


echo "{'success': true, 'updateInfo': '" . $infoString . "'}";
```

---

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        id: 'form-file',
        emptyText: 'Select image',
        name: 'image-upload',
        buttonText: 'Browse',
        buttonConfig: {
            iconCls: 'upload-icon'
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        //action: 'submit',
        text: 'Upload',
        handler: function () {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            form.submit({
                url: 'uploadproc.php',
                waitMsg: 'Loading data...',
                success: function (form, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Successful upload!', 'Image update info: ' + action.result.updateInfo);
                },
                failure: function (form, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failure!', 'Error info: ' + action.result.error);
                }
            });
        }
    }],
});
```

Try googling about json, php json response, ajax/json...